# Visual Studio не видит, что я включил C++20 компилятор

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++17, c++20

я достаточно много программируют на С++ в Visual Studio, но тут возникла большая проблема: Visual Studio никак не хочет "видеть" то, что я включил для проекта std:c++latest, то есть C++20.
Как бы, беда не в том, что программа выдаёт ошибку, когда я использую std::any или std::variant, а в том, что IntelliSense не хочет видеть и подсказывать мне данный код. То есть если даже IntelliSense выводит ошибки о том, что пространство имён std не содержит any, то программа всё равно без ошибок скомпилируется.

Хотелось бы узнать, как исправить эту проблему. У меня Visual Studio 2019, а компилятор точно установлен последней версии.

Comment: #define _HAS_CXX17 превращается в 0, также как и _HAS_CXX20.

Comment: проверь стоит у тебя release/debug 64/86

Comment: Стоит Debug x86, но с x64 версией тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Данный вопрос уже рассматривался, правда, ответ я нашёл на англоязычном StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980146/cant-choose-c-language-standard-in-visual-studio-2019

Ответ я нашёл, поэтому помощь более не нужна.